# Fixing third party code: "error: ‘enable_if’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type"

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

While trying to build a third party application, I found that one of its dependencies (https://github.com/genome/joinx) would not compile cleanly with newer compilers. In the process of tidying it up (the code looks unmaintained since years), I got stuck with a compiler error I can't quite figure out.

The issue is in this file:

```cpp
#pragma once

// Utilities for comparing things / establishing orderings.

#include <boost/utility/declval.hpp>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Tags for use with enable_if

// Compare objects return an int <0, =0, or >0 to establish an ordering
// (cf. strcmp)
struct CompareBase {};
// ComparePred objects are predicates (e.g., less than)
// (cf. std::less)
struct ComparePredBase {};

template<typename Op>
struct DerefBinaryOp {
    Op op;

    explicit DerefBinaryOp(Op op = Op())
        : op(op)
    {}

    template<typename ValueType>
    auto operator()(ValueType const& x, ValueType const& y) -> decltype(op(*x, *y)) {
        return op(*x, *y);
    }
};

// Given a "Compare" function, convert it to a less than predicate.
template<
          typename T
        , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<CompareBase, T>::value>::type
        >
struct CompareToLessThan : ComparePredBase {
    CompareToLessThan(T cmp = T())
        : cmp(cmp)
    {}

    template<typename U>
    bool operator()(U const& x, U const& y) const {
        return cmp(x, y) < 0;
    }

    T cmp;
};

// Given a "Compare" function, convert it to a greater than predicate.
template<
          typename T
        , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<CompareBase, T>::value>::type
        >
struct CompareToGreaterThan : ComparePredBase {
    CompareToGreaterThan(T cmp = T())
        : cmp(cmp)
    {}

    template<typename U>
    bool operator()(U const& x, U const& y) const {
        return cmp(x, y) > 0;
    }

    T cmp;
};

// This is a helper class that defines relational operators
// (>, <, ==, !=, ...) for simple structs that define value_type
// and have a single member: value_type value;
template<typename T>
struct ValueBasedRelOps {
    friend bool operator<(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return lhs.value < rhs.value;
    }

    friend bool operator>(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return lhs.value > rhs.value;
    }

    friend bool operator<=(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return lhs.value <= rhs.value;
    }

    friend bool operator>=(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return lhs.value >= rhs.value;
    }

    friend bool operator==(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return lhs.value != rhs.value;
    }
};
```

And my compiler spews out errors:

```
/home/einar/Download/Sources/joinx/src/lib/common/RelOps.hpp:34:36: error: ‘enable_if’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   34 |         , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<CompareBase, T>::value>::type
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~
/home/einar/Download/Sources/joinx/src/lib/common/RelOps.hpp:34:45: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
   34 |         , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<CompareBase, T>::value>::type
      |                                             ^
/home/einar/Download/Sources/joinx/src/lib/common/RelOps.hpp:52:36: error: ‘enable_if’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   52 |         , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<CompareBase, T>::value>::type
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~
/home/einar/Download/Sources/joinx/src/lib/common/RelOps.hpp:52:45: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
   52 |         , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<CompareBase, T>::value>::type
      |                                             ^
```

I'm unfamiliar with `std::enable_if` and the previous searches on SO did not yield a solution similar to my problem. What's the exact cause of the error, so I can start working from there to fix it?

Comment: Did you `#include <type_traits>`?

Comment: No, it wasn't present in the original code. I can say it works with that, thanks.

Comment: Some compilers include some other standard headers in their standard headers. But this is not guaranteed throughout different versions. One of your standard headers probably included `type_traits` first, and now no longer does that. This is why you should always include all the things you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To help you "find the fish" in the future rather than be given a fish:

`error: ‘enable_if’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type`  Means that enable_if more than likely is unknown to the compiler at that point of usage.

Searching for "std::enable_if" will lead you eventually to this link
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

You will note the line `Defined in header <type_traits>`.

This leads to the question "Has this header been included?".

Comment: I've reported this issue upstream (https://github.com/genome/joinx/issues/20), although the project seems to be abandoned so y'know